# Ubuntu 18.10 constantly crashing

Tags: gnome, kernel, crash, acer, 18.10

My laptop is an Acer Predator Helios 300, Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ, 16GiB RAM, NVIDIA GTX1060 6GB (nvidia-driver-410) running Ubuntu 18.10.

Ubuntu is very frequently crashing (something between every 15 to every 30 minutes maybes). The screen freezes, audio keeps playing for a short while, screen goes back, reboots me in login.

For some reason I have no `/var/log/system*` log files. But in `journalctl` I found this:

**`gnome-session-binary[1395]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop`**

More details:

```
 at-spi-bus-launcher[1572]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1024"
 at-spi-bus-launcher[1572]:       after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
 systemd-logind[1078]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-shell[1443]: Connection to xwayland lost
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' killed by signal 15
 gsd-color[2345]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_AU_Optronics_gdm_120
 gnome-session[1395]: gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
 gnome-session-binary[1395]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```

I also found this in `/var/log/apport.log`:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 4340) Sat Nov 24 00:15:43 2018: called for pid 31248, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
 ERROR: apport (pid 4340) Sat Nov 24 00:15:43 2018: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-shell (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-shell")
 ERROR: apport (pid 4340) Sat Nov 24 00:15:43 2018: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

 ERROR: apport (pid 4340) Sat Nov 24 00:16:14 2018: Unhandled exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/share/apport/apport", line 633, in <module>
     os.chmod(report, 0o640)
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash'
 ERROR: apport (pid 4340) Sat Nov 24 00:16:14 2018: pid: 4340, uid: 1000, gid: 1000, euid: 1000, egid: 1000
 ERROR: apport (pid 4340) Sat Nov 24 00:16:14 2018: environment: environ({})
```

gnome extensions installed:

```
Ubuntu Dock
KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support
Impatience
Places Status Indicator
Clipboard Indicator
Hide Activities Button
Refresh Wifi Connections
No Topleft Hot Corner
system-monitor
Extensions
User Themes
Sound Input & Output Device Chooser
NetSpeed
Workspaces to Dock
Hide Top Bar
Auto Move Windows
Removable Drive Menu
Coverflow Alt-Tab
Apt Update Indicator
Touchpad Indicator
Advanced Volume Mixer
```

This is **really** annoying me and I want to stay on Ubuntu but there is no way I can work on my projects like this. For now I will be using Windows..

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS? It is more debugged and polished than 18.10, so I think it is worth trying (at least try it live without installing, and use the boot option `nomodeset` to make the nvidia card work). If you install and want good performance, you should test some of the nvidia proprietary drivers in order to find the best one for your graphics card.

Comment: "*reboots me in login*" - so the machine/OS Ubuntu actually causes a reboot, you see post, plymouth & it reboots?  or is GNOME crashing which occurs as you describe but then gnome restarts itself (you are thrown back to login screen; no reboot)?.   I'd check all your extensions are for the correct version (so abi/api's match), and then ideally start adding back very slowly until you work out which is causing issues.

Comment: `journalctl -b  -1 -e` will show you the system logs leading up to the last boot.

Comment: There's a 99% chance that one of your (too many) GNOME extensions is causing your problem. `Workspaces to Dock` was known to cause many such problems, and I don't know if the author fixed it. Disable ALL your extensions and see if the problem goes away. If so, re-enable a few extensions at a time until you break it. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I have (after a long struggle) been able to downgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. The session under Wayland quickly crashes as usual, but the session on X with NVidia driver 410 seems to be very stable (been running my computer since the morning with no crash/freeze whatsoever). The only thing is that no desktop icon appears, even though my Desktop folder is non empty. The crappy thing is the touchpad support on X compared to Wayland. I am assuming the problems I was having are related to Wayland directly, or to Intel Graphics driver (since wayland only runs on intel).

Comment: Okay just would like to say that I was able to bring the desktop icons back by installing Gnome Tweaks and setting show icons on desktop to true. I thought it was a default setting.

Comment: Have You tried with the latest `nvidia-driver-430` binary driver ?